# logging in then out from facebook causes a crash when trying to reLogin android

Tags: android, facebook

I added a login button to my application, it's working just fine, but my problem is when I added a logout button in the next activity, it's logging out but when I try to login again my application crashes!

**I used this code to logout :** `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`

**and here's how my java code of the activity where I login:**

```
public class ConnexionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b_bb, b_back, ee, b_inscrp_formulaire, fb;
EditText tb_pseudo, tb_mdp;
int id;
String name, gender, email, birthday;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
Profile profile;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    /*List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
            "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");*/

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connexion);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    b_inscrp_formulaire = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_inscrip_formulaire);


    fb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb);


    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setText("");

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday"));
    //"user_photos", "email","user_birthday", "public_profile"
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : connexion interrupu!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : Erreur de connexion!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    });




    b_bb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_bb);
    b_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_back);
    tb_pseudo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox_pseudo);
    tb_mdp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox_mdp);


    /////////////
    ee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ////////////

    b_bb.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    b_bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bb_selec);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                    b_bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bb);

                    break;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    b_bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (isAuthorized()) {

                Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MenuPActivity.class);
                menu_p.putExtra("pseudo", tb_pseudo.getText().toString());
                startActivity(menu_p);
            } else {
                openDialog();
            }

        }
    });


    b_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConnexionActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });


    ee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MenuPActivity.class);
            menu_p.putExtra("pseudo", "Easter");
            startActivity(menu_p);

        }
    });

    b_inscrp_formulaire.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, InscriptionActivity.class);
            startActivity(menu_p);

        }
    });


    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());

            Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MenuPActivity.class);
            menu_p.putExtra("pseudo", profile.getFirstName());
            startActivity(menu_p);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecté : " + profile.getFirstName() + " " + profile.getLastName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : connexion interrupu!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : Erreur de connexion!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    });


    fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(ConnexionActivity.this,
                    Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends", "email"));
            /*facebook permissions : "user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile"*/
            profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile();

            //to verify if a login happened or not!!
            if (profile != null) {
                // user has logged in
            } else {
                // user has not logged in
            }


        }
    });


    //To log out of FB:
    /*LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();*/

    //TODO: check if the user is logged in or not
   /* profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile();
    if (profile != null) {
        // user has logged in
    } else {
        // user has not logged in
    }*/

}

private Boolean isAuthorized() {

    if (tb_pseudo.getText().toString().equals("Admin")
            && tb_mdp.getText().toString().equals("0000")
            ) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

public void openDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Mauvaise combinaison \"Pseudo\", \"Mot de passe\"");

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

        }
    });


    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}


public void graphRequest(AccessToken token) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

            //showing infos about the connected client!!
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), object.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)");
    request.setParameters(b);
    request.executeAsync();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}

}
```

Comment: Please add log..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I got an answer to this:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

fb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb);

loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday"));
        //"user_photos", "email","user_birthday", "public_profile"
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : connexion interrupu!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : Erreur de connexion!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());

                Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MenuPActivity.class);
                menu_p.putExtra("pseudo", profile.getFirstName());
                startActivity(menu_p);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecté : " + profile.getFirstName() + " " + profile.getLastName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : connexion interrupu!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : Erreur de connexion!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(ConnexionActivity.this,
                        Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
                /*facebook permissions : "user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile"*/
                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile();

                //to verify if a login happened or not!!
                if (profile != null) {
                    // user has logged in
                } else {
                    // user has not logged in
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did?